# How do I know if my tenancy has been updated to SPFx v1

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

How can I tell if my tenancy has been updated to SPFx V1 ?

Comment: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. According to [Release Notes GA](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-GA), if your tenant has GA version, then uploading the app package to app catalog will say it's valid.
2. Open `/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx` page and using developer tools check if there are JavaScript files loaded from https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-17.019. If yes, then your tenant has GA version.

Comment: I have https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-loader_en-us_e10f93aa29d8eff41e6d241bc285557f.js  so I suspect not.

Comment: Yes, this means that your tenant was't updated yet.

Comment: By end-of-day Monday you should be upgraded.